# No passwd entry for user 'mssql' sqlsrv on Linux

Tags: linux, docker, sqlsrv

I use the `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017` docker container to run a mssql server. I tried to change the collation like this:

```
echo "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" | /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set-collation
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

```
No passwd entry for user 'mssql'
```

How is it possible to fix this error?

---

I created a new user with `useradd mssql`, but now I get this error if I run the command:

```
sqlservr: Unable to open /var/opt/mssql/.system/instance_id: File: pal.cpp:566 [Status: 0xC0000022 Access Denied errno = 0xD(13) Permission denied]
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: PAL initialization failed. Error: 101
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks the latest `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server` fix such issue, if you insist on the old, next could be the procedure to fix all user/permission issue:

```
cake@cake:~/20211012$ docker run --rm -it mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest /bin/bash
SQL Server 2019 will run as non-root by default.
This container is running as user root.
To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.
root@4fd0bdf1d21c:/# useradd mssql
root@4fd0bdf1d21c:/# mkdir -p /var/opt/mssql
root@4fd0bdf1d21c:/# chmod -R 777 /var/opt/mssql
root@4fd0bdf1d21c:/# echo "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" | /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set-collation
Enter the collation: Configuring SQL Server...

The SQL Server End-User License Agreement (EULA) must be accepted before SQL
Server can start. The license terms for this product can be downloaded from
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746388.

You can accept the EULA by specifying the --accept-eula command line option,
setting the ACCEPT_EULA environment variable, or using the mssql-conf tool.
```